# Creating a 2D array of coordinates in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a 2-Dimensional array of coordinates with random values between 1 and 4 at each position. I am currently having trouble initialization the values. Here is my current code for the method:

```
public void createMap(){
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i ++){
        for (int j = 1 ; j < 20; j ++) {

          coord[i][j] = setCoordinates(random.nextInt(4) + 1, random.nextInt(4) + 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(getCoord());
}
```

and this method:

```
public Coordinates setCoordinates (int row, int column){
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    return coord[row][column];
}
```

and the coordinate class:

```
public class Coordinates {
int row;
int column;


public void setColumn(int column){
    this.column = column;
}

public void setRow(int row){
    this.row = row;
}

public int getRow(){
    return row;
}

public int getColumn(){
    return column;
}

}
```

The result is always `null` in the console.
How can I change my code to actually initialize the values in the array? 
The end goal is to create a coordinate grid for a 2D game. Is there anything specific I should keep in mind if I'm trying to use this on a GUI GridPane such as return type? Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do within the for loop but obviously that's totally wrong lolol @Caleb_McCreary

Comment: Actually I do have `Coordinates[][] coord = new Coordinates[20][20];` as well. Would that be causing the issue? @Caleb_McCreary

Answer (score 0):

```
public Coordinates setCoordinates (int row, int column){
   Coordinates c = new Coordinates();
   c.setRow(row);
   c.setColumn(column);
   return c;
}
```

In this case coord should be `Coordinates[][] coord = new Coordinates[x][y];`

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get much from your explanation but I am showing you two full examples with Coordinates class and without:

example 1, with you setCoordinate function that returns the Coordinates object:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Coordinates[] coord = new Coordinates[20];

        createMap();
    }

    public static void createMap(){
        Coordinates[] coord = new Coordinates[20];

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
            coord[i] = setCoordinates(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 99) + 1, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 99) + 1);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
            coord[i].getCoord();
        }
    }

    public static Coordinates setCoordinates (int row, int column){
        Coordinates c = new Coordinates();
        c.setRow(row);
        c.setColumn(column);
        return c;
    }

    public static class Coordinates {
        int row;
        int column;

        public Coordinates(){
            //constructor
        }

        public void setColumn(int column){
            this.column = column;
        }

        public void setRow(int row){
            this.row = row;
        }

        public int getRow(){
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn(){
            return column;
        }

        public void getCoord(){
            //just return and print the coordinates
            System.out.println("ROW: " + this.getRow() + "      COL: " + this.getColumn());
            //change void to return and return value if you like :)
        }

    }
}
```

if you want you can play around with the getCoord() and return array of coordinates by knowing that [0] is row and [1] is column like this:

```
public int[] getCoord()
        {
            int coords[] = new int[2];

            coords[0] = this.getRow();
            coords[1] = this.getColumn();

            return coords;
        }
```

and then you can print this like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
            int coords[] = coord[i].getCoord();
            System.out.println(coords[0] + " - " + coords[1]);
        }
```

and example 2, without returning Coordinates

```
package com.company;

import java.io.Console;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        Coordinates[] coord = new Coordinates[20];

        createMap();
    }

    public static void createMap(){
        Coordinates[] coord = new Coordinates[20];

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
            coord[i].setCoordinates(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 99) + 1, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 99) + 1);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
            coord[i].getCoord();
        }
    }

    public static class Coordinates {
        int row;
        int column;

        public Coordinates(){
            //constructor
        }

        public void setColumn(int column){
            this.column = column;
        }

        public void setRow(int row){
            this.row = row;
        }

        public int getRow(){
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn(){
            return column;
        }

        public void setCoordinates (int row, int column){
            this.setRow(row);
            this.setColumn(column);
        }

        public void getCoord(){
            //just return and print the coordinates
            System.out.println("ROW: " + this.getRow() + "      COL: " + this.getColumn());
            //change void to return and return value if you like :)
        }

    }
}
```